# help with custom shortcode that stopped working

Tags: php, shortcode

A while back I wrote a shortcode for my site, and it just recently stopped working. I'm wondering if someone can help.

The shortcode is called paramtext. What it does is check the value of a certain parameter in the page url, and if it meets the criteria, wordpress displays whatever is within the shortcode.

Example:

```
[paramtext param="hi" val="yes"]hello![/paramtext]
```

This would say "hello!" only if the url had `?hi=yes` in it.

The shortcode works fine, except for in one type of situation. That is if its within the href of a link.

Example:

```
<a href="http://website.com/[paramtext param="abc" val="xyz"]pagename[/paramtext]" target="_blank">link</a>
```

It used to work just find (in this case, the link would be `http://website.com/pagename` or just `http://website.com`), but recently it stopped. Now, no matter what the parameter is in the url, the link it gives is `http://website.com/[paramtext param=`. It doesn't realize that the shortcode is actually a shortcode.

I tried deactivating all plugins, and also changing the theme to twentyfourteen, but nothing helped. Maybe it's a wordpress update that killed it?

Here's my shortcode - if anyone can advise how to fix it, I'd really appreciate it!

```
function paramtext( $atts, $content = null ) {  
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'param' => 'param',
    'val' => 'val',
    'hide' => false,
), $atts ) );
if ((strtolower($_GET[$param]) == strtolower($val) && $hide == false)||(strtolower($_GET[$param]) != strtolower($val) && $hide == true)){
    $return = $content;  
}else{
    $return = "";
}
return $return;
```

}

Comment: PS: If any more info or clarification is needed please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress 4.2.3 made some changes to the way shortcodes work in order to fix a security issue. See here: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/07/23/changes-to-the-shortcode-api/

This is most likely the cause of your problem. See the Shortcodes with Bad Quotes section, and the accompanying workaround suggestion.

Comment: Wow! What an easy fix, after spending hours debugging  :). I changed the double quotes within the shortcode to single quotes, and whew - it works! I can't thank you enough!!!!